# Prevent browsers from customizing browse button

Tags: css

How can I prevent browsers from customizing buttons, such as Chrome, for example, does.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/TeZxanR.jpg]

I would like to remove that "No f... sen". What is the best way to do that?

Comment: You can't. That's like asking how to remove the filename box on other browsers' versions of the file input.

Comment: *You can* using something called *Shadow DOM*. But it's not implemented well yet. Search for it online. Paul Irish has some info about it on his website too.

Comment: Even if you could, *should* you?  Showing the user what file they've selected (or in this case, *no file selected*) is an accessibility feature.  If your goal is to display this information differently, this information is protected for security reasons (trying to read the value of a file input reads `c:\fakepath\filename.txt`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to google for "Css style file input" ;)

This will lead to: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Styling of `<input type="file" />` is really tricky.

Answer (score 3):

The only way you can remove the text part in non-IE10+ browsers to make it transparent:

```
input[type=file] { color: transparent; }
```

However, I’d not recommend that, as you will also not be able to see the text when a file has been selected either.

For IE10, you can style it with:

```
input[type=file]::-ms-value { /* styles here */ }
```

In WebKit you can style the button itself with:

```
input[type=file]::-webkit-file-upload-button { /* styles here */ }
```

While in IE10 you can do the same with:

```
input[type=file]::-ms-browse { /* styles here */ }
```